# Will Microsoft continue supporting C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I've found C++/CLI to be a very powerful language for wrapping C/C++ libraries with .NET.

I believe it's much better than using PInvoke for C for various reasons.

However, when I've upgraded [my project](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) to Visual Studio 2010, I've found that it has less support for C++/CLI.

Examples:

- [Targeting the 3.5 framework with the Visual C++ 2010 compiler is not supported.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560606/c1001-compiler-crash-on-c-cli-project-in-vs2010-when-target-framework-is-3-5) - Won't be fixed.
- [No coverage highlighting.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/462971/the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-popup-when-clicking-on-show-code-coverage-coloring) - Should be fixed in next version.
- No Intellisense - [501921](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501921/c-cli-intellisense#), [459187](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/459187/intellisense-unavailable-for-c-cli), [455686](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/455686/intellisense-unavailable-for-c-cli). By Design!
- [Useless CA1811 warning.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560050/getting-ca1811-when-i-call-a-private-method-from-a-public-method-in-c-cli) - Won't be fixed.
- [Uselss CA1806 warning.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559820/getting-ca1806-on-c-cli-code-when-catching-exceptions) - Postponed.

Microsoft claims:

> I want to make it clear that while we
>   can't address this issue, we reduced
>   support for C++/CLI only due to time
>   and resource constraints. This is NOT
>   an indication that we are distancing
>   ourselves from the technology.

But, C++/CLI never had really good support, and if the current version of VS has less support, what does the future holds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt anybody has a truly definitive answer, even (for example) Herb Sutter, who works as an architecture on Visual Studio. The problem is simple: Microsoft's direction is determined (largely) by market pressures and customers. If a *lot* of people complain long and loudly about the problems, Microsoft will probably see fixing them as important -- and see C++/CLI as more important in general. If few people complain, chances are pretty good that they'll assume few people are using C++/CLI, and it'll remain marginalized.

To an extent, I think it's a self-fulfilling prophecy: they never *really* supported it quite well enough to make it a viable alternative, so it's never gotten a lot of use. That, quickly results in vicious circle of fewer users leading to less development leading to still fewer users...